# Proper Rails association setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations

Im setting up a reminder service that sends deals via email in relation to a persons interests AND city.. Basically, the user inputs important dates (friends bday, anniversary ect) and the interests of that special person.

I want to send them deals based on 1)the users city and 2)the interests of the related person

How should i setup my associations for the Deal model?

What i have so far..

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :city
has_many :person_interests, :as => :person
has_many :interests, :through => :person_interests

end

class City < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :name 
  belongs_to :province
  has_many :users
end

class PersonInterest < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :interest
  belongs_to :person, :polymorphic => true  
end

class Interest < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :person_interests
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you have so far? What's not working or doesn't seem ideal to you?

Comment: @rfunduk Added what i already have.. Everything is fine and collecting the information i need fine.. just wondering how to associate the new deals model with interest and city.

Comment: would deals be a belongs_to for both interest and city?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a deal could apply to more than one interest, you'd start with something like:

```
class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :interests
  belongs_to :city
end

class City < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :name 
  belongs_to :province
  has_many :users
  has_many :deals
end

class Interest < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :person_interests
  has_many :deals
end
```

And then you could do something like

```
@relevant_deals = @city.deals.where(:interest_id => 'abc')
```

or

```
@relevant_deals = @interest.deals.where(:city_id => 'def')
```

Comment: Thanks! i dont really care if the deal can belong to more than one interest or not... whatever's easier to setup.. i dont mind having the admin adding a deal multiple times if it needs to associate with more than one interest...

Comment: so then how would it work on the city and interests models... For example, in city (a) there can be a deal for interest (a) and in city  (b) there will be a different deal for interest (a)

Comment: and do i need to do anything to the interest model?

Comment: Does a City have more than one deal?  If so, yes, you need has_many.  I'll add the same idea on Interest model.  It's the same concept.

Comment: oh ok great, thanks.. Yes a each city has a deal for each interest (a pre-populated list of like 20 selected by the user during registration)